# I am using Fullcalendar library in my react project. When i change month next/prev the api is getting called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar library in my react project. When i change month next/prev the api is getting called multiple times.

Below is my code and this is how I am importing fullcalendar

```
        <FullCalendar
                          plugins={[
                            dayGridPlugin,
                            timeGridPlugin,
                            interactionPlugin,
                            googleCalendarPlugin,
                          ]}
                          headerToolbar={{
                            left: "prev,next today",
                            center: "title",
                            right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
                          }}
                          contentHeight="auto"
                          initialView="dayGridMonth"
                          editable={true}
                          selectable={true}
                          selectMirror={true}
                          dayMaxEvents={true}
                          weekends={true}
                          select={(e) => handleaddEventShow(e, false)}
                          eventClick={(e) => handleaddEventShow(e, true)}
                          events={(
                            fetchInfo,
                            successCallback,
                            failureCallback
                          ) =>
                            getCalendarData(
                              fetchInfo,
                              successCallback,
                              failureCallback
                            )
                          }
                        />
```

Comment: please add the whole code, that looks like its missing something

Comment: "the api is getting called multiple times."...do you mean specifically the API from which you fetch your event data? If so then that's intentional. Your API is supposed to only return events for the current range of dates in the view each time. The range of dates is supplied to you via the callback arguments. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function for more info

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. on `dateClick` prop I have a function which is setting the state for 3 states and API is being called exactly 3 times. Even clicking the close button of `<Dialog/>` (Material UI)  re-fetches the event.